# Application Controller with before_filters that execute first and last

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to set up my application controller to do a before_filter before all other before_filters, AND also a before_filter after all other before_filters. How can I do this?

In rails the application controller is executed first, then  other controller is executed. so I can get either authorize to happen first, or more_info to happen last, but not both.... I have tried various prepend_before_filters, append_before_filters with no luck (the main issue seems to be that append_before_filter is an alias for before_filter, so it doesn't actually append more_info last)

example below:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :authorize # should be first
  before_filter :some_other_action
  before_filter :another_action 
  append_before_filter :more_info # should be last
end

class OtherController < ApplicationController #Approximately 30 other controllers
  before_filter :get_other #all actions in all controllers should be in between authorize and more_info
  before_filter :various_action
  before_filter :different_action 
  before_filter :mas_acciones 
  before_filter :mais_acoes 
end
```

Expected:
1. authorize
2. get_other
3. more_info

Actual:
1. authorize
2. more_info
3. get_other

Using Rails 4.0.3

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 before_filter :authorize # should be first
 before_filter :more_info # should be last
end

class OtherController < ApplicationController
  append_before_filter :authorize,:get_other,:more_info #should be in between authorize and more_info
end
```

`get_other` will be in between authorize and more_info.

Comment: This does work, but I was hoping for a solution where the other controllers don't need to know about the application controller methods. Are there other possibilities?

Comment: i didn't get your question properly? actually what you need?

Comment: I added more information to the original question. I have many other controllers, and each have many before filters. I want to reduce the amount of repeating code. With your answer I will repeat the append_before_filter line hundreds of times throughout my application

Comment: not sure this is good or not,create one array and put controller class name like `array = ["OtherController"]` and loop in `array.each do |kclass| kclass.constantize.class_eval do   append_before_filter :authorize,:get_other,:more_info end` like that you try,i will try tomorrow better way to do this.